# Emacs call-process as sudo

Tags: emacs, elisp, sudo

UPDATE

I have accepted @Sean answer, with some small modifications.

```
(defun sudo-shell-command (buffer password command)
  (let ((proc (start-process-shell-command
           "*sudo*"
           buffer
           (concat "sudo bash -c "
                   (shell-quote-argument command)))))
    ;;; Added to @Sean answer to display the passed buffer
    (display-buffer buffer '((display-buffer . nil)) nil)
    (process-send-string proc password)
    (process-send-string proc "\r")
    (process-send-eof proc)))

(defun sudo-bundle-install (password)
  (interactive (list (read-passwd "Sudo password for bundle install: ")))
  (let ((default-directory (concat default-directory
                               "./fixtures/test-kitchen-mode-test-run/"))
    ;;; Added from accepted answer below by @sean
    ;;; need a buffer to display process in.
    (generated-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*test-kitchen-test-setup*")))
    (sudo-shell-command
      ;;; pass reference to generated process buffer by name.
      ;;; Need to add a defun to get the current test-kitchen buffer 
      ;;; if it exists to use, but that is outside the scope of the question.
      (buffer-name generated-buffer)
      password
      "bundle install; bundle exec berks install")
    (clear-string password)))
```

---

Say I need to call a process in elisp, and that process requires sudo priveleges. Example, running Ruby's `bundle install`:

```
(let ((generated-buffer (generate-new-buffer "*test-kitchen-test-setup*")))
  (display-buffer generated-buffer '((display-buffer . nil)) nil)
  (call-process-shell-command
    (concat "cd " (concat default-directory "./fixtures/test-kitchen-mode-test-run") 
            "; sudo bundle install; sudo bundle exec berks install;")
    nil generated-buffer t))
```

The `bundle` command requires `sudo` to install gems correctly. How can I call this shell command in elisp with sudo, enter the password, and still be able to display the results in the generated window?

Comment: `sudo bundle install`?!

Comment: @lunaryorn For chef development at work, all the workstations use system ruby. I personally use rvm on my home machines, but the workstations aren't set up with /usr/local owned by `my_example_usr:staff`, so that means using `sudo`. Pick your battles, I guess.

Comment: @lunaryorn Also, this sudo call is only executed by default in the mode I am writing in the ert tests setup. I will provide an option to use sudo for executing bundle exec, but it will be off by default in the actual mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a helper function that executes a single shell command as sudo with a supplied password:

```
(defun sudo-shell-command (buffer password command)
  (let ((proc (start-process-shell-command
               "*sudo*"
               buffer
               (concat "sudo bash -c "
                       (shell-quote-argument command)))))
    (process-send-string proc password)
    (process-send-string proc "\r")
    (process-send-eof proc)))
```

You might apply it to your situation like so:

```
(defun sudo-bundle-install (password)
  (interactive (list (read-passwd "Sudo password for bundle install: ")))
  (let ((default-directory (concat default-directory
                                   "./fixtures/test-kitchen-mode-test-run/")))
    (sudo-shell-command
     "*test-kitchen-test-setup*"
     password
     "bundle install; bundle exec berks install")
    (clear-string password)))
```

Comment: I think process send string was exactly what I was looking for! I'll plug it in in the morning and let you know what I find. I assume that the password will show up in plaintext in logs somewhere, though, correct?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, no.  I was going to mention, I'd be careful to make sure that sudo actually always asks for the password.  This code just supplies the password to whichever process reads its standard input first.

Comment: This works, but doesn't dispay the generated buffer.

Comment: I have updated the question above to include the code changes necessary to display the generated buffer properly. Please update your answer and ping me so that I can remove the UPDATE section in the question above and you get all the credit you deserve for helping me out with this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a file with your password:

```
(defun my-run-command-under-sudo (password command &rest cpsc-args)
  "Run COMMAND under sudo with your PASSWORD.
Other arguments are passed to `call-process-shell-command'
 and should start with BUFFER (the output destination).
NB: this is _not_ secure: it creates a temp file with your password."
  (let ((password-file (make-temp-file "elisp-sudo")))
    (with-temp-file password-file (insert password))
    (unwind-protect
         (apply 'call-process-shell-command
                (concat "sudo " command)
                password-file cpsc-args)
      (delete-file password-file))))
```

Now you can do:

```
(let ((default-directory (concat default-directory "./fixtures/test-kitchen-mode-test-run")))
  (my-run-command-under-sudo "my-password" "bundle install" t)
  (my-run-command-under-sudo "my-password" "bundle exec berks install" t))
```